# Why is CSS file not linking to HTML file in VSCode?

Tags: html, css

I have both files in the same folder but for some reason I can't get them to link, here's what I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Do i need to add the whole link to the directory? I've been told that's unecessary if they're in the same folder. I have tried multiple browsers and I get the same results.

Edit: this is what I have on VSCode, this is the very first time I try HTML and CSS and my programming knoweledge is very limited, sorry for my ignorance at this point.[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O6OM.png)

Comment: OK, based on what you have just posted in an image (and we do prefer code posted on the site in general), having just "style.css" in your link is correct.  You stylesheet has style specified for paragraphs (<p> tags), but there are no paragraphs in your HTML document, so you won't see any styling diffs.

Comment: ill keep the image thing in mind for next time and the issue is solved! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If both files are in the same folder, e.g.

- site

  - page.html
  - style.css

Then your link need only be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: still doesn't work unfortunately, that was the first thing I tried

Comment: Well, if you could possibly provide us with some more detail about how your site is laid out and possibly the technology you are using, we might be able to help.  Otherwise we're just guessing :)

Comment: @Mer - additionally, how sure are you that the CSS file is not being served as opposed to the CSS styles inside just not being structured properly.  If you look at the network tab in the browser dev tools, do you see a 404 Not Found for the CSS file?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand the "CSS file is not being served as opposed to the CSS styles inside just not being structured properly", and I am not really getting any errors, just the page not being edited when i modify it in the css file

Comment: also i added a screenshot for reference in case that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the correct relative path to the href-Attribute.

Just delete the "css/"

[Look here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: tried it the first time, still doesnt work

Comment: Your html file is in the same direction as the css file?

Comment: yes, both in the very same folder

Comment: you forgot to add a p-Element in your code: <p>Hello World!</p>

Comment: dammit it was such a dumb detail thank you it works now!!